# How to read PowerShell's debug stream from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, debugging, stream

I am using PowerShell 2.0 to write data to PowerShell's debug stream via the [Write-Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug?view=powershell-5.1) function. Now I want to read that stream from the same PowerShell script. I tried to redirect the debug stream with "2>&1", but this works only for the error stream.

Is there a way to read the PowerShell debug stream from a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also experiment with your function that will be called instead of cmdlet `Write-Debug`. Here is a very quick implementation:

```
$global:__DebugInfo = new-object PSObject -prop @{
    Enabled=$false
    Messages=new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
}

function Write-Debug {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Message)
    $d = Get-Command Write-Debug -CommandType cmdlet; & $d $Message;
    if ($global:__DebugInfo.Enabled) {
        $global:__DebugInfo.Messages.Add($Message) > $null
    }
}

function Enable-Debug {
    $global:DebugPreference = 'continue'
    $global:__DebugInfo.Enabled = $true
}

function Disable-Debug {
    $global:DebugPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
    $global:__DebugInfo.Enabled = $false
}

# Test
Enable-Debug
Write-Debug 'this is test debug message'
Write-Debug 'switch off'
Disable-Debug
Write-Debug 'this message should not be included'

Write-Host "Debug messages:"
Write-Host ($__DebugInfo.Messages -join "`n")
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done but it is complex.  See Oisin's writeup on [script logging](http://www.nivot.org/2009/08/19/PowerShell20AConfigurableAndFlexibleScriptLoggerModule.aspx).  In general, this issue of being able to redirect streams other than stdout and stderr has been [logged as a suggestion on the connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/297055/capture-warning-verbose-debug-and-host-output-via-alternate-streams).  You might want to vote on it.